# how to calculate datetime based on data from mysql server in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that store a datetime format in mysql server

```
Donor_id || Req_id || Donated_Time
3        || 1      || 2018-09-14 00:00:00
```

And I want to calculate a four months difference from that date. And what i wanna to do is

```
if($dbdate == $4monthsdiffdate) {
u can donate blood
}
```

And i dun know how to calculate that 4 months difference. Need some light

Comment: from the date in the table to what date? why not calculate the date in the select query itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datetime, something like this:

```
<?php
$dbdate = new DateTime("2018-09-14 00:00:00"); // here you must replace with your database column value
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $dbdate->diff($now);
if($diff->y >= 1 || $diff->m > 4) {
    do something 
} else {
   do something   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer posted by Dimitrov will not work if the difference is more than one year, so you have to check also if the year is greater or equal to 1

```
$diff = date_create("now")->diff(new DateTime($dbdate));
if($diff->y >= 1 || $diff->m >= 4) {
    // You can donate blood
}
```